# Apple Metal Sample Texture In Vertex Shader

Tags: macos, metal, vertex-shader

I am trying to sample a texture inside a Metal vertex shader.

Receiving the following error: "AGX: AGX: Texture read/write assertion failed: depth > 0"

Setup for rendering:

```
    MTLSamplerDescriptor *samplerDesc = [MTLSamplerDescriptor new];
samplerDesc.normalizedCoordinates = YES;
samplerDesc.rAddressMode = MTLSamplerAddressModeClampToEdge;
samplerDesc.sAddressMode = MTLSamplerAddressModeClampToEdge;
samplerDesc.tAddressMode = MTLSamplerAddressModeClampToEdge;
samplerDesc.minFilter = MTLSamplerMinMagFilterNearest;
samplerDesc.magFilter = MTLSamplerMinMagFilterNearest;
samplerDesc.mipFilter = MTLSamplerMipFilterNotMipmapped;
id<MTLSamplerState> ss = [device newSamplerStateWithDescriptor:samplerDesc];

[ commandEncoder setVertexSamplerState : ss atIndex : 0 ];

[ commandEncoder  setVertexTexture : l_Texture_Height_Field
                             atIndex : CTI_Gradient ];
```

Vertex Shader:

```
vertex PVertex vertexShader_mkali ( uint vertexID [ [ vertex_id ] ],
                                        constant Vertex3D *vertexArray [ [ buffer ( CVI_Vertices ) ] ],
                                        constant vector_uint2 *viewportSizePointer [ [ buffer ( CVI_ViewportSize ) ] ],
                                        constant shader_Data_mkali &vertex_Shader_Data [ [ buffer ( CVI_ShaderData ) ] ],
                                        texture2d < float > heightTexture [ [ texture ( CTI_Gradient ) ] ],
                                        sampler smp [ [ sampler ( 0 ) ] ]
                                   )

{
    PVertex outVertex;
    float2 l_Point = vertexArray [ vertexID ].position.xy;
    l_Point.x = mkali_noxstep( -1.0, 1.0, l_Point.x );
    l_Point.y = mkali_noxstep( -1.0, 1.0, l_Point.y );
    float4 l_Texture_Heightfield = heightTexture.sample ( smp, l_Point );
    outVertex.position = float4 ( vertexArray [ vertexID ].position + float3 ( l_Texture_Heightfield.x, 0.0, 0.0 ), 1.0 );
    outVertex.color = float4 ( 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0 );
    outVertex.size = 30;       
    return outVertex;
```

}

Anybody have any ideas?

thank you,
Nikki

Comment: I do not know vertex-shader, but typically this type of question is more likely to get a useful response if you provide a little more details about what you were doing when you received the error.  A snippet of the code or steps you were using to perform the sampling would be useful.

Comment: What is your texture format?

Comment: If I had to guess, you are passing the wrong `depth` somewhere, either in `getBytes` or a render pass descriptor. It doesn't seem to have to do anything with vertex shader itself.

Comment: Signed 16bit Float

Comment: Per depth the texture is coming from Apple Motion FxPlug as a source texture ( I don't control that ).  I will try rendering to an intermediary where I can control the details of the texture.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for the error by any chance? Like, can you step over each line and see at which point the error appears in the terminal?

Comment: How do you create said texture? Please provide the code used to create the texture.

Comment: MTLTextureDescriptor *textureDescriptor     = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat : MTLPixelFormatR32Float. width : l_Number_Of_Samples_lO height : 1 mipmapped : NO ];

oL_Texture = [ device  newTextureWithDescriptor : textureDescriptor ];

MTLRegion region = {
            { 0, 0, 0 },
            { static_cast < NSUInteger > ( l_Number_Of_Samples_lO ), 1, 1 } }; 
[ oL_Texture  replaceRegion : region. mipmapLevel : 0. withBytes : l_LUT_LO_Data
                        bytesPerRow : l_Number_Of_Samples_lO * sizeof ( float ) ];

Comment: Tried using code to make the source look better.  Failed.